# How can I use a browser as gui for java?

Tags: java, html, user-interface, client

I want something similar with php/jsp in java, but not on the server side, but on the client side.

Maybe I can make a html file with i/o, or with some net.* classes. But what can I use for the button on the html page ?

Thank you

Comment: The question is very unclear. Firstly, jsp *is* Java. What exactly are you trying to do? Also, Java on client-side can be one of three things: a stand-alone application, a JNLP (web-start) application (which is designed to be delivered over web but otherwise behaves as a stand-alone), and an applet (which runs inside the browser). Most people these days agree the #3 is a horror, but sometimes (rarely) it has it uses. Not related to Java, a button on a HTML page is `<input type="button"/>`. You can look up any HTML intro on `INPUT` tags. If you want it really in Java, look at `java.awt.Button`.

Comment: Is this a web based application ? How is your client communicating to the server ?

Comment: no server, no applet, nothing complicated;
for short: the gui are the html pages
  the button is the JButton
  post/get (maybe) are the listeners
  input is the JTextArea etc 
Html to act as swing ...

Comment: Don't think you'll get it to run in a browser without a webserver (though you can set one up on the same machine) but if you use one of the components capable of rendering html you could probably hook into requests and react appropriately.

Comment: Use Javascript? Your HTML button can have an onclick event handler which executes whatever Javascript you want.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the c# webbrowser component? just a browser in your form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). You write your UI and logic in Java and it gets compiled into Javascript that then runs client-side in the browser.

Comment: As a conclusion, client programming in html should be made with javascript. GWT and Wicket makes this more easier by programming in java.

Comment: Aloha ... I found only 6 x questions with [gui], [html] and [java].

It would be quite rational to CHOOSE to write logic in a functional language (C++, Java, etc.) and use a general purpose Descriptive language (e.g. Html and CSS, SGML, XML:<something>) for an interactive interface definition. 

After all it has worked for database since the 1960-s.

Comment: C++ and Java are not functional languages, but object-oriented ones.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean you want to run an application on the local machine, but use an HTTP-based interface. In that case, you need the application to act as a web server on the local machine, then launch a web browser for "http://localhost:8080/" (or whatever port the application is listening on).

To implement this, you need an embedded web server such as [Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/).

Answer (score 0):

install resin on your PC
http://caucho.com/resin-4.0/admin/starting-resin.xtp
(and JDK)

can run jsp,html on http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague... maybe something like [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) or [MozSwing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozswing/) will help??